# Restore Unity after fiddling with CCSM

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I was happily using Unity when I fiddled around with a setting on CCSM (`CCSM -> Window Management -> Static Application Switcher`). A confirmation box followed which said that the new setting would override an existing combination (or something like that, not sure). And because I was not sure, I clicked on the close button on the top left instead of "`Ignore`" or "`Override`" options.

This resulted in the top panel in Unity to show incorrectly (it did not disappear, but just showed random colours). So then I went to `CCSM -> Preferences -> Profiles` and `Unity` was the Profile that was already selected. I clicked on "`Reset to Defaults`" button just below the profile name.

After this, the whole side bar and the top panel of Unity has disappeared.
I restarted the PC and it still did not appear. All I can do is press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` (that's the only shortcut I know) to restart the PC from Unity.

Any idea on how to restore Unity back to its original beauty?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @andrewsomething pointed out in the comments above, the solution lies in this thread: [How do I reset my Unity configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

You can start terminal (by logging into Ubuntu Classic) and type the following:

```
unity --reset
```

Then restart and its done, back to where you left it earlier.

If there is also a need to remove all custom favorites from the launcher, one can type:

```
unity --reset-icons
```